# How can I maintain Date Range Searched Result in Django views and Pagination

Tags: python, django

I have a date range search query with the total of the result which is displayed in django templates using loop in a table with pagination. And whenever the date range result exceeds one page and I click on the next page, the following page now display all the list of query that was initialize firstly in the views thereby loosing the whole Date Range Result.

Here is my views code:

```
def SearchIncomeRange(request):
    listIncome = Income.objects.all()
    searchForm = IncomeSearchForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
    listIncome = Income.objects.filter(date__range=[searchForm['start_date'].value(),
                            searchForm['end_date'].value()
                        ]
    )

    
else:
    searchForm = IncomeSearchForm()

paginator = Paginator(listIncome, 5)
page = request.GET.get('page')
paged_listIncome = paginator.get_page(page)

#Calculate total amount of Date Range Result
total = listIncome.aggregate(total = Sum('amount')).get('total') or 0

context = {
    'listIncome':paged_listIncome,
    'searchForm':searchForm,
    'total':total,
}

return render(request, 'cashier/search_income_range.html', context)
```

If you take a look at the code very well, the first query fetches the whole income whereas the second query in the if statement does the date range search and any time I click on next page in the template it is the result of the first query for all income list that returns instead of displaying only the records in the following page. Thanks for your anticipated answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening becouse when you change the page, you are not sending a POST request. So your entire function won't work. Paginator is made to build a single page with pagination inside, not to build a request type function

```
def SearchIncomeRange(request):
    searchForm = IncomeSearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if searchForm:
        listIncome = Income.objects.filter(date__range=[searchForm['start_date'].value(),searchForm['end_date'].value()])
    else:
        listIncome = Income.objects.all()


    paginator = Paginator(listIncome, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paged_listIncome = paginator.get_page(page)

    #Calculate total amount of Date Range Result
    total = listIncome.aggregate(total = 
    Sum('amount')).get('total') or 0

    context = {
    'listIncome':paged_listIncome,
    'searchForm':searchForm,
    'total':total,
    }

    return render(request, 'cashier/search_income_range.html',context)
```

simply, change the logic from finding a POST to find if there is a FORM

Comment: for your answer but only that the code does not make the form to search and display the date range result.

Comment: I fixed It. Try It now

Comment: thanks once again. Actually your answer has solved my problem 90% but the Issue is that Pagination is not working on Searched result. In fact, My concern is to have pagination work on Date Range Search Result but your edited answer usually looses the search result once the next page button is clicked thereby displaying nothing again on the template. Thanks for your anticipated answer again.